# Allowing only a particular child to overflow

Tags: css

In the mentioned html: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/KiranKumarDash/4b7rga8q/3/)

There are three childs to the parent div. The parent div is a square of 300px and has the css rule set to `overflow: hideen` and thus hides everything that overflows. I am looking for a solution using which I can allow a particular child to overflow and others must not.

Say, for example in my example, I would like to allow the div with class child1 to overflow but any other class must not. Something like the below picture:

[image]

So, is this achievable?

**html:**

```
<div id="parent">
 <div class="child1">
 </div>
 <div class="child2">
 </div>
 <div class="child3">
 </div> 
</div>
```

**css:**

```
#parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
}

.child1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}

.child2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
}

.child3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/KiranKumarDash/4b7rga8q/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do following:

1. Give `position: fixed;` to `.child1`.
2. `position: relative;` to `#parent`
3. `margin-left: 50px;` to `.child2`

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4b7rga8q/6/)**

Comment: This works, except if you make the window very small and then scroll vertically then `.child1` will remain static on the page. Perhaps not a problem to the OP, but something to consider.

Answer (score 1):

I got the effect, however not without modifying the HTML. So perhaps not the answer you are looking for. Nevertheless, here goes:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child1">
  </div>
  <div id="innerParent">
    <div class="child2">
    </div>
    <div class="child3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
}

#innerParent {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.child1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}

.child2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
}

.child3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
}
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dxbp8fLL/**

Answer (score 1):

You can create another element `wrap` with `position: relative` and then you can use `position: absolute` on element that you want to overflow parent

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}
#parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
}
.child1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
}
.child2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.child3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="parent">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
    <div class="child3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what are you trying to do, but seeing it the other way around, you could force the elements to limit to the height of the parent instead of using `overflow:hidden`

```css
#parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
}
.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.child1 {
  background: red;
  max-height: initial;
}
.child2 {
  background: blue;
}
.child3 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child child1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque consequatur quod velit numquam assumenda, quibusdam sit excepturi incidunt voluptates eum, rem. Est magnam asperiores vitae ipsam esse, deserunt. Doloremque, voluptatum.
  </div>
  <div class="child child2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum sapiente maiores ipsum adipisci esse nesciunt ullam dignissimos, veniam reprehenderit. Nesciunt atque, deserunt! Ea quam doloremque sit quae in saepe dolorem.
  </div>
  <div class="child child3">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi ea nobis, dignissimos beatae, quia quas magni in. Hic nulla eius et autem, vero quia, iste, quisquam repellat tempora, voluptates aliquid.
  </div>
</div>
```